# Why is the download button using anchor tag in react js not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello i want to create a download button in react js, so that user can download a pdf file by clicking that button.
i used the anchor tag with download attribute but it is not working. when i click the download button, it says "failed no file" in the small pop up window.

```
<a href="./test.pdf" download> Download </a>
```

The pdf file is in the src folder.

Comment: put that pdf file inside your public folder and then give the path /test.pdf without the dot

Answer (score 1):

inside the file that has

```
<a href="./test.pdf" download> Download </a>
```

do this rather

```
import testPDF from './test.pdf';
<a href={testPDF} download> Download </a>
```

this solution will work, assuming both the pdf and the jsx file are within the same directory "./src"

Comment: also you can add an attribute to the anchor tag and extend the download attribute, by specifying how you would like to name the file when the client download it to their computer. like this:
<a href={testPDF} download='test.pdf'> Download </a>
in this case the file what arrives to the client's computer will have the name of test.pdf, of course they can change it but it's a clean way to make sure they will find that file